# Creating a .jar file using ImageIcon class and JLabels in java

Tags: java, jar, jlabel, imageicon

I am making a Cluedo boardgame in java and I cannot get my images to show up when converting it to a .jar file.I am adding the images on top of one another so I used JLabels(new ImagIcon ("..")) like so.To add the images and now the images can't be seen when I create a .jar file. Just wondering if there is any way to do without editing my code a significant amount. I have read all stackoverflow answers on this issue and none of them solves this particular problem. Here is what the board game looks like when I run it in Eclipse. 
[image]

When I convert it to .jar file it no longer displays the board or any of the players.

Comment: You can try this JButton btn = new JButton("Show Icon");
btn.setIcon(new ImageIcon(YourClassName.class.getResource("/your/packages/path/icons/main_room.png")));
If you want look at to [this example](https://github.com/Coder-ACJHP/Hotel-Properties-Management-System/blob/master/src/com/coder/hms/ui/main/Main_UpperToolbar.java)

Answer (score 1):

`ImageIcon(String)` expects that the `String` value is "file" reference to the image residing on disk.

If you have externalised your resources then you need to ensure that the path you are using is correct.  Remember, the "working directory" in which the Jar is executed isn't always the same as the directory that the Jar is stored in.

To this end, it's generally recommend to "embedded" the images (and other resources) within the Jar itself.  This way you can simply perform a lookup for the resource regardless of where it's installed.

The means by which you embedded resources is slightly different for each IDE, but it basically requires that the images are included in the Jar and a specific location/package.

An important note, when embedded in the Jar, the resources can no longer be referenced as if they "files", because they're not, they are part of the Jar/Zip archive and need to be referenced in a different manner.

To load embedded resources you need to use `Class#getResource`, which returns a `URL` or `Class#getResourceAsStream` which returns a `InputStream`.

In most case, the first is enough.  While `ImageIcon` does take a `URL`, it is generally recommended to use `ImageIO.read`, have a read through [Reading/Loading images](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details.

The advantage of this is two fold:

1. It blocks until the image is read, meaning the image is fully realised when the method returns
2. It throws an `IOException` when the image can't be read, which is way more meaningful, as `ImageIcon` fails silently

So, all that would accumulated down to something like...

```
new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(instanceOfMyAwesomeGameObject.getResource("/path/to/resource/ResourceName.png"))));
```

Comment: Sorry I don't know what I am supposed to put in for "instanceOfMyAwesomeGameObject"

Comment: I still can't get this to work, I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: So, two things, one instanceOfMyAwesomeGameObject is what every class you’re using. Two I have no other context to your problem to make suggestions other then: Make sure the images are included in the jar and the path you are using to load the images is correct

Answer (score 0):

I think it comes from the path to your images. The image path for sources is probably not the same as for .jar